# How do I prevent an invalid character from being copied/pasted in my input box?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a JQuery code that is able to prevent invalid characters from being typed in my input box:

```
$('input#input-firstname').on('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
   }
});
```

I just discovered that invalid characters such as '%' can be copied and pasted into the input box. I really need to restrict. How do I prevent this

Answer (score 1):

Use the `input` event instead of the `keypress` event:

```
$('input#input-firstname').on('input', function (event) { ... })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste` event

```js
$('input#input-firstname').on('keypress paste', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input-firstname" />
```